# STM32F UART stops receicing after writing with SPI to FRAM (I2C to EEPROM)

Tags: stm32, uart, i2c, spi

I do use `UART` on a `STM32F405` just fine (receiving and transmitting).

```
(while (HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart4, receiveBuffer, UARTRECEIVEDBUFFERSIZE) != HAL_OK);)
```

Now I added an external `FRAM` (`FM25V02A`) to my circuit and use SPI to read and write to it. Reading works fine. But after writing to the `FRAM` (transmit completes, data is stored away) the `UART` does no longer receives data !? The `UART` however still transmits data like before.

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{...}
```

The interrupt callback is not going to be fired anymore.

This is how I do write to the `FRAM`.

```
opcodeWREN[0] = 0b00000110;
opcodeWRITE[0] = 0b00000010;

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //chip select
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, opcodeWREN,1,5);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, opcodeWRITE,1,5);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, sendFRAMBufferByte,240,5); //transmitting 240byte of data
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

I did have the same problem writing with `I2C` to an `EEPROM`.

Whats going on? Any ideas what I should look at? Thanks! Stefan

Comment: Usart spi & i2c is better to program using registers as youhave the control over the hardware.  Using libraries you are prone to the library errors.

Comment: I was too much focusing on interrupt priorities and preemption issues, that I did not see (the most obvious) a blocking code in the data input parser. The data send to the UART in combination with the "store to fram" command did block the parser. So it works now...

Comment: Did you try to use non-DMA version of the UART calls. Might be a DMA conflict?